# JQuery Mobile datepicker disappears

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

When I open my Datebox from http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2 in my JQM page, the datepicker disappears after .5 sec.
This only happens on an smartphone / tablet. On desktop browsers it shows fine.

I also noticed when I open the picker on my tablet, the header flickers a bit. Maybe this is sign of a refresh of something?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Could we see your source code or a js fiddle link?

I am guessing that you tried to disable any other scripts on your page and tried to troubleshoot this issue.

Did you have a the following code as well on your page?
      
setTimeout("$('#datetime').trigger('datebox', {'method': 'open'});", 6000);

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I don't know why but if there is some plain text between the HTML  tag and the JQuery Mobile pages () it works.

```
<body>plain text <div data-role"page"></div> </body>
```